# Implementing quadratic linear regulator (lqr) in simulink

Tags: control, matlab, simulink, state-space

I am working with a non-linear model of a hot-air balloon. I have linearized the system, found the operating point, the state space matrices and I know these are correct:-

```
xss = [328.79, 0, 500];
uss = 139.29;
yss = 500;

A =[   
   -0.0033         0   -0.0000;
    0.2051   -0.0200    0.0007;
         0    1.0000         0]

B =1e-3*[1.0000;0;0]

C = [0     0     1]

D = 0
```

I defined my weight matrices \$R_1 \$ and \$R_2 \$ (also sometimes known as \$Q \$ and \$R\$) and used the MATLAB command `lqr` to find the controller gains.

```
R1 = [1e-7 0 0; 0 1e-7 0; 0 0 1e-7]
R2 = [1]
[K S e3] = lqr(A,B,R1,R2)
```

In theory, this controller should keep the system running at the operating point. I built the system in Simulink, but the states doesn't seem to be at the operating point at all: -

[image]

Am I missing something in my Simulink model to make it work correctly? Am I not using the regulator properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essence of the LQR-based feedback controller is to place the pole of the dynamical matrix to the LHS plane, so that your closed-loop system \$\dot{x}=(A-BK)x\$ will be stable. But \$x\$ here doesn't need to be the state, for tracking problems, it is the error \$e=\text{ref}-x\$ which gives you \$\dot{e}=(A-BK)e\$ where \$\text{eig}(A-BK)<0\$. Thus you will see the error converging to zero as time flies.

But the system derived from your Simulink has the form of \$\dot{x}=(A-BK)x+B\cdot\text{ref}\$ where your desired point is not an equilibrium point at all, which gives the non-convergence result in your simulation. After a slight modification of the reference signal connection that gives \$\frac{d}{dt}(\text{ref}-x)=A(\text{ref}-x)+BK(\text{ref}-x)\$, you will happily force the system to track the target.

Comment: `\$` is for inline math, while `$$` is for their own paragraph. \` is used for `code`.

Comment: That's exactly what I need! I didn't find the inline math mode in the text editor previously. Thanks a lot!